# NetBeans Platform application on android, is this possible?

Tags: android, rcp, netbeans-platform

I am just simply wondering if it is possible to port an NetBeans Platform (RCP) application onto an Android OS device, and how? Would I have to redesign my GUIs? I am assuming that any libraries (APIs) I have also used in the original source code would have to be replaced with the Android ones.  I am new to Android development so please forgive me if the question is dumb. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that it is possible without rewriting at least some parts of the platform basic modules.

I also think that netbeans platform is relatively heavy for the end machines running android.